# change active color of nav-pills

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is the code i'm using to make the pills in my navbar active..

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">

  <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>"><% yield (:home)%><%= link_to "Home", root_path%></li>
```

however it uses the default blue color as "active" how should i change this?

this is what i have in my css already

```
.nav>li>a:hover,

.nav>li>a:focus{

 background-color: #5c8a36;}
```

even with this (the color should be green) it still shows up as the default blue color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line (`.nav>li>a.active,`) to your css:

```
.nav>li>a.active,
.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
   background-color: #5c8a36;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `<a>` there!

```css
.nav>li:hover,
.nav>li:focus,
.nav>li:focus {
  background-color: #5c8a36;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">

  <li class="">
    Home
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I changed a bit and now working.

```
.nav-pills>li.active>a,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
   background-color: #5c8a36;
}
```